# Dynamic Chart Title From Data Values

Tags: kibana, vega-lite, vega

I want to take the title of my vega-chart directly from the data which are base of the chart. For example the title of this chart should be 'charttitle':

```
{
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
"data": {
"values": [
{"quater":"1", "sales":"100", "title":"charttitle"},
{"quater":"2", "sales":"200", "title":"charttitle"},
{"quater":"3", "sales":"300", "title":"charttitle"},
{"quater":"4", "sales":"400", "title":"charttitle"}
]
},

"mark": "bar",
"encoding": {
"x": {"field": "quater", "type":"ordinal"},
"y": {"field": "sales", "type": "quantitative"},
},
"title": ???
}
```

In pseudo code it could look like this:

```
"title": (select title from data limit 1); or in standard sql

"title": (select top 1 title from data)
```

but how can i achieve that in vega?

Comment: Do you want a solution in Vega or Vega-Lite?

Comment: Vega or Vega-lite doesn't matter. Both would be fine, cause I want to use it within a kibana-dashboard

Comment: I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"quater": "1", "sales": "100", "title": "charttitle"},
      {"quater": "2", "sales": "200", "title": "charttitle"},
      {"quater": "3", "sales": "300", "title": "charttitle"},
      {"quater": "4", "sales": "400", "title": "charttitle"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "quater", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "sales", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "title": {"text": {"expr": "data('source_0')[0].title"}}
}
```

Comment: You are the greatest. I tried it in so many ways without success. Where can I find the documentation of the data-part ("data('source_0')[0])?

Comment: Thanks. I cobbled it together by referencing https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/

Answer (score 0):

You can check this website. There are a lot of examples.

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/

[image]

Comment: Of course I know the documentation of vega/vega-lite. But I didn't find an example which matches my problem